# What is a seeded question?

Tags: discussion, seeded-questions

Is it a question one knows how to solve, in order to flesh out the beta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's exactly it. It's a phrase many people here are using to refer to a question you ask, not because you actually want to know the answer, but because you want the site to appear full of good interesting questions when it opens up to the public.

Comment: Another important reason to ask seed questions is to make decisions about what's allowed and what isn't (explaining the many seed questions which suck).